# Valid Provisioning Profile not working for git repository

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, xcode7, provisioning-profile

I just created a provisioning profile(distribution) which includes features like push notifications etc... the flow went smoothly and app accepted by apple, every thing is working fine in the production. As app going forward the features increased and going complex coding in the following versions so for safe side i thought to maintain git repository for the app.

Git implementation is done and new features added in the development. Coming to testing part everything working fine including push notifications.

But while submitting to the app store via Xcode 7.1, i am getting (no matching provisioning profiles found for "Applications/project_name.app").

I have tried all the suggestions from stack over flow but no result. For my understanding i just changed version number and uploaded old project again(the project before implementing Git i.e, live version of App store), it is uploading successfully.

I am not getting what exact problem with the provisioning profiles

My Observation: The provisioning profiles are not expired/invalid. if expired/invalid it should not allow me to upload my old project again.

Comment: You're going to need to show your project's build settings.  Ideally, show the build settings for your the old project (working) and the new project (not working).

Answer (score 1):

The only provisioning files that matter are the ones in `~/Library/MobileDevice/Provisioning Profiles/` (not any that might be in your repo or local directories or on the Apple developer site)

I use fastlane's `sigh` command (specifically `sigh manage`) to make sure this folder is correct. https://docs.fastlane.tools/

One easy thing to do

1. Copy all of the files from `~/Library/MobileDevice/Provisioning Profiles/` to some other place
2. Put in just the correct App Store distribution profile (so that this is the only .mobileprovision file there)
3. Archive an App Store build

If this doesn't work, then your project might be set up wrong (or you are wrong about your profile file).

Comment: Do you think this would work to manually copy with a script provisioning profiles stored in the git repository?

Comment: Yes. It’s just a folder with files. You can manage it however you want

Comment: You also need to have the proper certificate and private key in your keychain.