# Store Bitrise Provisioning Profiles in the git repository

Tags: provisioning-profile, bitrise

Is there a way to store my app's provisioning profiles along the code in my git repository and make Bitrise install them on runtime? This instead of manually uploading the profiles to Bitrise.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is just a matter of copying the `*.mobileprovision` files to the proper user path.

```
cp ./Provisioning/*.mobileprovision ~/Library/MobileDevice/Provisioning\ Profiles/
```

Solution based on https://stackoverflow.com/a/40728419/1049134

Answer (score 0):

Why not create a repository using [Fastlane Match](https://docs.fastlane.tools/actions/match/) approach and use [Fastlane Match Integration](https://www.bitrise.io/integrations/steps/fastlane-match) so that you can manage certificates and profiles for not only yourself, but also for your team as well?